# Duplicate items when the message is sent

Tags: java, android

When the user submits an image instead of appearing only one image appears two appears, then causes each message that I write to be repeated. The receiving user does not receive duplicate things, but the one that sends yes. Something strange, because if I leave the conversation and re-enter the messages and images that have been duplicated do not appear anymore.

Here is the code that I think is creating the conflict.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder, int i)
    {
        String messageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Messages messages = userMessagesList.get(i);

        String fromUserID = messages.getFrom();
        String fromMessageType = messages.getType();

        usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(fromUserID);

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))
                {
                    String receiverImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                    Picasso.get().load(receiverImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });


        messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.messageSenderPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageViewHolder.messageReceiverPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);



        if (fromMessageType.equals("text"))
        {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderId))
            {
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_messages_layout);
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
            }
            else
            {
                messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.receiver_messages_layout);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else if (fromMessageType.equals("image"))
        {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderId))
            {
                messageViewHolder.messageSenderPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.get().load(messages.getMessage()).resize(1000, 1000).centerInside().into(messageViewHolder.messageSenderPicture);
            }
            else
            {
                messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.messageReceiverPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.get().load(messages.getMessage()).resize(1000, 1000).centerInside().into(messageViewHolder.messageReceiverPicture);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is print screen of the bug of duplicate messages when sent.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps the list view is out of sync?

Comment: I don't know. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

clear the receiving datalist before receiving data from firebase   ex. list.clear()